# TabulatorJS - Remote Pagination not working

Tags: javascript, php, tabulator

First off, my apologies if this isn't the correct location/tag to apply to this question.

I am utilizing Tabulator, a javascript library that can be found [here](http://tabulator.info/)

I've set up remote pagination for a page on a site, and the table populates with the data and will display X amount of pages set by last_page, however the data isn't actually split up between pages. All 535 results show on every page. The JSON being received from the server is in the correct format, the data is received and is populated in the table, however the data is simply not being split up among the pages.

Here is my constructor:

```
`var table = new Tabulator("#table-container", {
        autoColumns: true,
        index: 'Personnel',
        pagination: "remote",
        ajaxURL:"./get_request/getAnalyticsReport.php", //ajax URL
        ajaxParams:{
            Personnel: personnel,
            FirstName: firstName,
            LastName: lastName,
            ResourceAval: displayedResources,
            Months: monthsList
            }
        });`
```

I've already tried setting the paginationSize parameter to no avail. Do I need to modify my servers response so that it calculates the results to return based upon my desired number of rows and the respective page number? Currently, it is returning all of the rows. I'm assuming I just may not completely understand how tabulator works exactly in terms of remote pagination.

I greatly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction or help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set `pagination` to `'local'`.

This Parameter tells Tabulator if the pagination happens `'remote'`, which means the server should handle the pagination and return the correct data set. If you use `'local'` Tabulator knows that it fetches all data from server and should handle pagination itself.

Comment: Thank you very much! Of course it was something as simple as that, have a good one!